# How do I change the commit hash (`commit 43a1b08`) color in `git log` building a new format?

Tags: git

When I do a `git log`, using the default `--pretty=medium` format, it gives me output like this:

```
commit 80e7613 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Curt J. Sampson <cjs@cynic.net>
Date:   2018-05-03 12:42:03 +0900

    python/pytest: Customizing test discovery
```

The `commit 80e7613` part is printed in yellow. I'd like to change this color.

I could do this with a custom format, but that would be annoying duplication and also wouldn't change any of the numerous other [formats] (both built-in and custom where I use `%C(auto)%h`).

How can I set this globally, for all printing of hashes using the default color?

I'm most often using git version 2.11.0 (the default package for Debian 9), but I use various other versions as well. Bonus points are given for config file compatibility with old versions of Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [config option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colordiffltslotgt), which by default is yellow

```
git config diff.color.commit <your color>
```

See test [`t/t4207-log-decoration-colors.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3622a4ee94e4916cd05e6d96e41eeb36b941182/t/t4207-log-decoration-colors.sh#L11), which seems to rely on `diff.color`

Comment: Ah! Even though I already have several settings for `color.diff`, I had skimmed over it in the docs because it didn't occur to me that they would put log-specific settings in there. (I don't think that `color.diff.commit` is actually ever used by `git diff`, is it? Though it does make some sense given that the diff colours would of course be used for `log --patch` output.) Also, thanks for the tip on looking through the tests to find answers for stuff like this.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I haven't seen diff.color.commit used by git diff itself. Also: https://github.com/git/git/blob/d0db9edba0050ada6f6eac68061599690d2a4333/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L177-L179